# C# Additional information: External component has thrown an exception

Tags: c#, error-handling

I'm getting this error

```
Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.
```

only when in debug mode, when I open up my program normally it works fine, but in debug mode it's throwing this error which I'm not sure why.

Here is the code it's throwing the error on.

```
                Thread tokenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new Action(() =>
            {                    
                using (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser())
                {
                    wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
                    wb.Tag = args.Account;
                    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                    wb.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/md.html", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));

                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
                }                  
            })));
```

and it's this line it's throwing it on in debugger.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
```

Could anybody point out my mistakes?

Comment: anything written in the windows logs. `Event Viewer`?

Comment: can you check for `InnerException`?

Comment: Nothing is written other than the error in the Event Viewer

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess could be this line: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, try to replace it with `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)`. When running it from the IDE the current directory could be different than running directly from explorer.

Comment: I'm just getting Assembly doesn't exist in this current context.

Comment: Did you add `using System.Reflection;`? And for the `Path` you have to have `using System.IO;`

Comment: Yep I have both, restarted the project and it's gone so. Will check this out and report back.

Comment: Error is still occurring